# How to do i correctly use fromNow(), momentjs expression in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, momentjs

It shows the correct amount of time when i add the following code.  When I refresh the page amount of time is 2015 years. 'dob': is a string like "2015-03-10".

```
var diffInDays = moment(Session.get('dob'), 'YYYY-MM-DD').fromNow(true);

Template.registerHelper('daysSinceBirth', function(input) {
  return diffInDays
});
```

In html template I have {{dob}}.

Comment: what is `input` param?

Comment: @user2292326 when you refresh the page, your session variables will be erased. In your case, you either need to ensure `dob` is set somewhere in the router or your template code after a refresh or you need to decide what a reasonable default is for your helper in the event that `dob` isn't defined.

Comment: @user2292326  Did the method posted in the answer work for you? Please accept it if it worked for you.

Comment: The suggestion didn't work.  I have a template helper for dob.  so when ever i put {{dob}} in a page it loads the dob string.

Comment: You said you are using it in a page as {{dob}} Could you please modify this and use {{daysSinceBirth dob}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unable to comment because I dont have enough reputation. So posting it here.

Try this:

```
Template.registerHelper('daysSinceBirth',function(dob){
  if(moment && dob){
        return moment(dob).fromNow();
    } else {
        return dob;
    }
});
```

In the template use {{daysSinceBirth dob}}.

Comment: This is great, thank you this is the first time i have seen a function in a registerHelper, +1 for inspiration i know i will use this again soon.

Comment: Sure. Thanks for editing the question and answer as well. I hope this will help more people.